# How to fix error java virtual machine not found error in apache storm?

Tags: apache, apache-storm

I am setting up apache storm in distributed mode. My Zookeeper is working fine. I am unable to start apache storm nimbus even.

I am following: http://chennaihug.org/knowledgebase/storm-multinode-installation/

Zookeeper config file:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/data/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=scarlet:2888:3888
server.2=plum:2888:3888
server.3=peacock:2888:3888
server.4=green:2888:3888
server.5=mustard:2888:3888
server.6=white:2888:3888
```

Storm.yaml:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "scarlet"
     - "plum"
     - "green"
     - "white"
     - "mustard"
     - "peacock"

nimbus.host: "scarlet"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
java.library.path: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
storm.local.dir: "/app/storm"
```

I started zookeeper using:

```
/opt/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkCli.sh -server scarlet:2181,plum:2181,peacock:2181,green:2181,mustard:2181,white:2181
```

Checked the status of zookeeper. 5 followers and 1 leader. All working fine.

I start apache storm using:

```
bin/storm nimbus
```

where it gives the error:

```
Unrecognized option: -client
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -client
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -client
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -client
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -server -Ddaemon.name=nimbus -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/opt/apache-storm-1.2.2 -Dstorm.log.dir= -Djava.library.path= -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /opt/apache-storm-1.2.2/*:/opt/apache-storm-1.2.2/lib/*:/opt/apache-storm-1.2.2/extlib/*:/opt/apache-storm-1.2.2/extlib-daemon/*:/opt/apache-storm-1.2.2/conf -Dlogfile.name=nimbus.log -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/apache-storm-1.2.2/cluster.xml org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus
2019-01-14 17:20:21,591 main ERROR Unable to create file /nimbus.log java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was java installation. Purged complete openjdk and re-installed it.

```
apt purge default-jdk default-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```