# how to fix Could not create the Java Virtual Machine in Apache Storm topology on cluster?

Tags: java, linux, apache-storm

I have setted up and started my zookeeper 3.8 and apache-storm 2.4 on my local machine. When I submit my topology to the local storm cluster its shown in the storm ui, but its not running. The log gives only this error message

```
2022-05-16 13:55:59.594 STDERR Thread-1 [INFO] [0.001s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:artifacts/gc.log instead.
2022-05-16 13:55:59.596 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'
2022-05-16 13:55:59.660 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
2022-05-16 13:55:59.669 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I am a little bit confused. I have build the topology with java 13 and run storm with java 13. I already found this thread [How to fix error java virtual machine not found error in apache storm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190115/)

and yes, I already did a clear reinstall.
My java version:

```
java --version
openjdk 13.0.7 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.7+5-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.7+5-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode)
```

What is wrong? I have a clean and working java on my computer, but it fails while starting the topology. How can I find and fix the problem?

Comment: I guess the real issue is to get the involved components to do more verbose logging. As in: you really need to see more information about that "fatal" exception that occurred. So look around whether there are command line / env vars that force zookeeper to do more logging.

Comment: _"Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'"_ the JVM is started with an unrecognized option. This could mean that you're using a version that is not compatible with your application launch script (and your application itself). I believe this option was removed in Java 11, so likely your application requires Java 8. Check its documentation, and use a compatible JVM version. The Storm documentation isn't very clear, but they specify they test against Java 8, which suggests they haven't considered incompatible changes in newer Java versions.